# Does red color in filename mean that there is an error somewhere?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea, version-control

Does red color of file names mean that there is an error somewhere?

[image]

Comment: This isn't actually Git, this is your Android Studio GUI. Git has its own (different) colorization of file names. Because you tagged your question [tag:git], you're getting both Git-specific answers and Android-Studio-specific answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

==> A **red** color in git means that those files **are not tracked**. 
You can check this by using:

```
git status
```

Once you add them(track them) the files become green. You can check it by `git status` alwyas.

Answer (score 2):

No. A red underline under filename denotes an error.

The red color of file names in your directory structure is most probably because you have enabled version control integration, e.g. Git, and have not added to version control for tracking.

Also note that white (or black in light theme) means unchanged file, blue means changed file, green means new file, and yellow means ignored file.